# SOQL Query - WHERE Condition: String column filter (Gov_DNB_dnb_confidence_code__c < '10') is not working

Tags: string, salesforce, soql

We have a SalesForce Table, where String column filter (Gov_DNB_dnb_confidence_code__c < '10') worked fine until last week.

To test a filter condition of 'NULL' and '', we updated couple of records values manually in SalesForce UI and the existing filter condition stopped working. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it was working fine before?

Less-than operator on strings does a lexicographical comparison on them. Strings are compared character by character until they are not equal or there aren't any characters left to compare.

```
'11' < '3' = true
'31' < '3' = false
'31' < '32' = true
'31' < '30' = false

'a' < null = false
'a' > null = false
'a' != null = true

'a' > '' = true
'a' < '' = false
'a' != '' = true;
```

Check against null and "" using != operator.
You can create a formula field to covert the string to a number and then use it in your SOQL and compare as a number.